# Check if a sequence of records contain a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find records not having a specific value in a sequence:

Customers Table:

[image]

For instance, I need to find all customers not having "Value F" on record.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE VALUE NOT IN 'Value F'
```

would also return values A, B, C, etc.

Comment: Select * from Customer where Value != 'Value F'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Customer c
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   Customer c2
                     WHERE  c2.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                            AND VALUE = 'Value F' )
```

NOT EXISTS can be used here.

Your NOT IN statement would need to look like this.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Customer
WHERE   CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT   CustomerID
                           FROM     Customer
                           WHERE    VALUE = 'Value F')
```

Comment: Don't encourage `NOT IN sub-qeury`... (Too many programmers have been fooled by it's NULL behavior.)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select customerid
from customers
group by customerid
having sum(case when value = 'Value F' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```